# Is there a way to find patterns based on categories in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, categories

I was wondering if there was a way to find patterns in a pandas DataFrame based on categories.

I know kmeans works for numeric values but my dataframe mainly consists of categories and dates:

```
car   check   jobcard   date        season 
merc  A       12A       01-01-2010  Winter
bmw   B       45A       03-02-2010  Winter
merc  A       12D       10-01-2010  Winter
bmw   C       25C       01-05-2010  Spring
vw    A       62B       01-08-2010  Summer
etc
```

It goes on for about 5000 rows, the dataset represents different types of checks that required repairs after the check, and I would like to see a pattern, for instance a BMW has problems mainly in the summer, or the 12A jobcard never happens in the winter. I have already made some scatterplots, but I was not able to get any results from them: Scatterplot

[image]

Is there any package that can provide a better overview or that can cluster categories in the same way kmeans does with numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a variation of k-means which is called k-modes, Published here

http://www.cs.ust.hk/~qyang/Teaching/537/Papers/huang98extensions.pdf

This is suitable for categorical data.

Please note here that the solutions you get are sensitive to initial conditions, as discussed here

https://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0603/0603120.pdf

see this for pythonic implementation

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is known as [Association Rule Mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). There are many google hits for that term, including some python-implementations. As a playground, you may use [Orange](https://orange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html).